# Tangents range for all pairs of points in a box

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Suppose i have a box with a lot of points. I need to be able to calculate min and max angles for all lines which go through all possible pairs of the points. I can do it in O(n^2) times by just enumerating every point with all others. But is there faster algorithm?

[image]

Comment: Is it correct that you take polar angles in range *[0; 2 pi]* of vectors *AB* for all the possible choices of different points *A* and *B*? In particular, the resulting range always has width at least *pi* (unless there is only one point).

Comment: @stgatilov i need to calculate angles with x-axis, i think the range is [0:pi)

Comment: I'm afraid that my solution uses range *[-pi/2; pi/2]*. In other words, it finds the range of *k*, which is line coefficient in *k x + b*.

Comment: @stgatilov can we just rotate the whole thing for -pi/2 and then apply your method? Anyway your approach is very good one!

Comment: Yes, you are right. We just need to check *(y, x)* and *(y, -x)* sorting orders too =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the idea of dual plane proposed by Evgeny Kluev, and my comment about finding left-most intersection point, I'll try to give an equivalent direct solution without any dual space.

The solution is simple: sort your points by *(x, y)* lexicographically. Now draw a line through each two adjacent points in the sorted order. It can be proved that the minimal angle is achieved by one of these lines. In order to get maximal angle, you need to sort by *(x, -y)* lexicographically, and also check only adjacent pairs of points.

Let's prove by the idea for min angle. Consider the two points *A* and *B* which yield the minimal possible angle. Among such points we can choose the pair with minimal difference of *x* coordinates.

1. Suppose that they have same *y*. If there is no other point between them, then they are adjacent. If there are any points between them, then clearly at least one of them is adjacent to *A* in our order, and all of them yield the same angle.
2. Suppose that there exists a point *P* with x-coordinate in between *A* and *B*, i.e. *Ax < Px < Bx*. If *P* lies on *AB*, then *AP* has same angle but less difference of *x* coordinates, hence a contradiction. When *P* is not on *AB*, then either *AP* or *PB* would give you less angle, which also gives contradiction.
3. Now we have points *A* and *B* lying on two adjacent vertical lines. There are no other points between these lines. If *A* and *B* are the only points on their vertical lines, then the *AB* pair is clearly adjacent in sorted order and QED. If there many points on these lines, obviously the minimal angle is achieved by taking the highest point on the left vertical line (which must be *A*) and the lowest point on the right vertical line (which must be *B*). Since we sort points of equal *x* by *y*, these two points are also adjacent.

Comment: I agree, that's much simpler.

Comment: having four points in lexicographical `(x,y)` order, `{ (0,0), (1,5), (2,1), (2,10) }`, isn't the smallest angle achieved by connecting the points 1 and 3? (ah, I see you've commented to that effect on the question already...).

Answer (score 2):

Sort the points (or use hash map) to find out if there are any horizontal lines.

Then solve this problem on dual plane. Here you only need to find the leftmost and the rightmost intersection points. Use binary searches to find a pair of horizontal coordinates such that all intersection points are between them. (You could quickly find approximate results just by continuing binary searches from these coordinates).

Then sort lines according to their tangents on dual plane. And for pairs of adjacent lines in this sorted order find intersections closest to those horizontal coordinates. This does not guarantee good complexity in the worst case (when some lines on primal plane are almost horizontal). But in most cases time complexity would be determined by sorting: O(N log N) + O(binary_search_complexity).

Comment: I think you can use the O(N log N + K) sweep-line algorithm for finding intersection points of line segments on plane. Since you need only the leftmost point, you have only to sort lines by *(-k, b)* lexicographically, then check intersections of adjacent lines. It will take O(N log N) in worst case.

Comment: @stgatilov How should i found all intesection points? There are n^2 of them. I can use bentley-ottmann for segments, not for lines i think.

Comment: @stgatilov: I cannot see how you could get O(N log N) worst case with sweep-line algorithm. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Ok, we need only to have the leftmost intersection points of *N* lines. We are going to solve it with sweepline. First place the sweepline to *x = -infinity*. Clearly, all the lines intersect the vertical line in the order of sorted *(-k, b)* lexicographically. Recall that sweepline algorithm calculates intersection points of each two adjacent lines and puts events to a heap. When we move our sweepline through an intersection point (i.e. event happens), order of lines changes (they are usually stored in balanced tree).

Comment: However, we need only the leftmost intersection point, so it is enough to stop on the first event. We don't need neither heap nor binary trees. Just calculate all the intersection points between adjacent lines, and choose the one that happens first. It is the leftmost intersection.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of going to dual plane.